# Flagging a question in a different language

Tags: discussion, review, flags, migration, languages

I spend a lot of time in the Triage. More and more I am seeing questions that are in a different language, I have been flagging these questions as "off topic/unclear what you are asking" and leaving a comment telling the user to re-ask the question on the respective Stack Overflow website for their language.

I was wondering why there is not an option to mark the question as belonging on a Stack Overflow in a different language like you can do if the question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Cross Validated](http://Stats.StackExchange.com)?

> [image: Off-Topic]

*Side question: is that the correct way to flag a question that is in a different language?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing it right; flagging as "unclear what you're asking" is the right action. [Don't (Google) translate the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315273/295232) into English; the author might not speak English at all. Leaving a comment is a good course of action as well.

One of the first rules of migration is ["don't migrate crap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/295232). In a foreign language, it's hard to determine whether a question is good enough. For example, something that looks like a well-worded question in Spanish could actually be 'just' a problem caused by a typographical error. Therefore, there's a policy in place that [questions (usually) aren't migrated between different Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275640/migrate-to-stack-overflow-portuguese/341038#comment614720_275641), not even by ♦ moderators.

That aside, there have been various requests to extend the list of migration targets, mostly on Meta Stack Overflow ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275640/4751173)). They've all been declined (so far).

Comment: I generally don't flag the question, but I do leave a GTranslated comment if I can identify the language in which the question was posted; the English version of my comment says that this is an English-language site, and questions should be posted in English; if there's a matching SO-in-that-language, the translated comment will also suggest that the user might want to look at the relevant SO.